# Count div clicks and run a function if the timer haven't stop

Tags: jquery, function, timer

hi to the community!!!

i'm try to build a kind of quiz,

i have 15 div's with class names:
.obj-(1 to 15) - for counting the div's
.obj - for hiding the div's

i want to count if a user have click the 15 available div's and if so, pass the time left in a form hidden input to $GET with php later or maybe in an another js function?

also i use `<div id="objects">0</div>` to count the div's clicked,
is it possible to accept only one click per count?
cause when i fast click the div it counts +1 all the time
this problem is the `fadeOut()` function but i need an effect there,

is all this possible?

here is the demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/dYqqv/3/

Comment: You ought to use `id` not `class` for your "obj-01" to "obj-15" divs (from your fiddle) `<div class="obj" id="obj-04">`. `id` is *meant* to be a unique identifier. (not that this helps with your problem)

Comment: thanks for this @Stephen, i don't use them yet, i will include them as id's later, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dYqqv/9/

EDIT:

Here's a Fiddle with time used instead of time remaining, as requested!

http://jsfiddle.net/dYqqv/14/

Comment: is it possible to pass the time spend in the seconds var? now it pass the time left, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sure. In your click event, simply unbind the click event handler for that div. See updated fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dYqqv/4/

Comment: thanks! the .one() is what i need, did you know how i count if the 15 divs have clicked to run a function? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can just use [`.one`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to bind the click event, this will ensure it is only clicked once.

```
$('.obj').one('click',function(){...});
```

Comment: thanks! but how i count if the 15 divs have clicked to run a function?

Comment: You could keep a counter that you increment, then check that counter on each click and if the counter is equal to the number of divs you have then call the function.

Comment: Philip here's a fiddle illustrating the concept. http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/dYqqv/8/